# Arrays are not validated in JSON Schema

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

I have a schema definition that is not doing a proper validation. Basically, it doesn't inspect anything inside the array and accepts any properties/values in it. I'm new to JSON validation, so I might be missing something.

This is the schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "JSON Validator",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "hash": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "date": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "uuid": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "task": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "order": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "step": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "meta": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "additionalProperties": false,
            }
        },
        "required": [
          "hash"
        ]
    }
}
```

A test JSON would be this:

```
{
  "task_N": [
    {
      "uuid": "asdfsdafa",
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "asdfasdd",
        "name": "dfasd"
      },
      "ip": "245245",
      "message": "asdfasd",
      "step": "",
      "is_archived": false,
      "creation_date": "34332423",
      "related_field": ""
    },
    {
      "uuid": "asdfsdafa",
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "asdfasdd",
        "name": "dfasd"
      },
      "ip": "245245",
      "message": "asdfasd",
      "step": "",
      "is_archived": false,
      "creation_date": "34332423",
      "related_field": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, there is no single match in the array properties, yet both the python library jsonschema and http://jsonschemavalidator.net give the the JSON as valid against the schema. I've been scratching my head for a few hours, does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It seems that I need to set not only the array properties to false, but the parent as well. Also, I needed to set it up as "patternProperties" with the proper regex. The finished schema is this:

```
 {
    '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
    '$id': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
    'type': 'object',
    'patternProperties': {
        '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$': {
            'type': 'array',
            'items': {
                'type': 'object',
                'required': [
                    'hash',
                    'date',
                    'uuid',
                    'task',
                    'author'
                ],
                'properties': {
                    'hash': {
                        'type': 'string'
                    },
                    'date': {
                        'type': 'string'
                    },
                    'uuid': {
                        'type': 'string'
                    },
                    'task': {
                        'type': 'object',
                        'properties': {
                            'name': {
                                'type': 'string'
                            },
                            'order': {
                                'type': 'integer'
                            },
                            'step': {
                                'type': 'integer'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'author': {
                        'type': 'object',
                        'properties': {
                            'id': {
                                'type': 'integer'
                            },
                            'name': {
                                'type': 'string'
                            },
                            'email': {
                                'type': 'string'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'meta': {
                        'type': 'string'
                    }
                },
                'additionalProperties': false
            }
        }
    },
    'additionalProperties': false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening for a few reasons, JSON schema requires your whole example to match the schema so you would need to have "task_N" as part of the schema.

Also, your schema is defined in `additionalProperties`, it should be `properties`.

Try this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "JSON Validator",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "task_N": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "hash"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "hash": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "date": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "uuid": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "task": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "order": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "step": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "meta": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, "task_N" is a variable name property. There is no defined amount of properties and the name will vary. Will it work with properties?